# "Before" in combination with the present state

Tags: word-usage

> Before he is the president,  he was a businessman.

> He is now the president and before that, he was a businessman.

Are these sentence fine? One of my fellow learners says "before" cannot be used in combination with a present state.  And he forget where he learned that. So we want to make sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is incorrect.  You do need to use the past tense:

> Before he **was** the president, he was a businessman.

The second sentence, or the other hand, is correct.

The word *before* does not *always* and *necessarily* force the past tense, and in the case of your second sentence, the word "now" definitely does force the present tense.  However, the word *before* does make us look at a specific point in time... that is, that point in time that marked the change from when the subject was not a thing, to when he/she/it became that thing.  In the vast majority of cases, this point in time was in the past.  He is the president, because he changed from being not-the-president to becomming the president on a specific date in the past.  The word *before* points us to that moment, so we use the past tense when talking about it... unless you expressly refocus our attention to the present with a word such as "now".

Instead of thinking of *before* as exclusively past tense, try to think of *before* as the tense of whenver the point of change is.  Here's a future tense sentence using before:

> Before he will become president, he will be a businessman.

And here's a present/habitual tense use, including a command:

> Before taking cookies from the cookie jar, wash your hands.

It all depends on when the change of state happens.

Comment: Thanks. "Before he was the president"  sounds like implying he is no longer the president.  I'm trying to understand this. Can I understand it this way: "Before he was the president"  points to the first second after he became the present？

Comment: Better still, you could say _Before becoming President..._ or _Before he became President..._

Comment: The future version is, "*Before he **becomes** president, ...*", not "*...**will become***".

Answer (score 0):

Your fellow learner is partly correct.

The correct sentence is:

> Before he **was** the president, he was a businessman.

If the *time* referred to in the "before" clause is in the present --like, he's the president *now*-- then the *tense* is the simple past, like that example. If the time the "before" clause refers to is in the *future time*, then we use the *present simple*:

> Before he **is** the president, I'm going to change some policies.

If it's in the past, we just use the past. This means "*Before he was president...*" doesn't indicate whether he's president now or not.

Comment: Thank you. If the order of the clauses chauses "He was a businessman before he was president",  does it still not indicate whether he is now president or not？

Comment: That's right. Regardless of ordering, the clause "*before he was president*" does not indicate whether he's still president now. It essentially means, "*before he **became** president*".